# How can I extract date from since time component

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have to extract date in the format MM-dd-yyyy in java from the since time value. Since time is the time at which the doucment is created. For example, if since time is **1452413972759**, date would be  "**Sun, 10 Jan 2016 08:19:32 GMT**" (Calculated from http://www.epochconverter.com/) . From this, I could get date in desired format but I am unable to code for the first step i.e., converting since time to date. Can someone help me?

I tried

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        java.util.Date date = df.parse("1452320105343");
        String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        System.out.println("Today is " + sdf.format(date));
```

But it gives parse exception.

Comment: Simply: `java.util.Date date = new Date(1452320105343);`. Note, however, that month, day and year are timezone-dependent, so you need to make sure you are doing the conversion in the appropriate timezone.

Comment: @AndyTurner. java.util.Date date = new Date(1452320105343); giving The literal 1452320105343 of type int is out of range  compile time error.

Comment: Chuck a `L` on the end of the literal to indicate it is a long.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't work because you're trying to parse a number of milliseconds as if it was a `MM/dd/yyyy` formatted date.

I would have expected the following code to work, where S represents milliseconds :

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("S");
java.util.Date date = df.parse("1452413972759");
String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
System.out.println("Today is " + sdf.format(date));
```

However it doesn't for some reason, displaying a date in the 1970 year.

Instead, the following code that parses seconds rather than milliseconds works for your needs :

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("s");
java.util.Date date = df.parse("1452413972");  // just remove the last 3 digits, or divide by 1000
String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
System.out.println("Today is " + sdf.format(date));
```

Or just follow the link from @mohammedkhan and use Date constructor rather than parsing a string :

```
java.util.Date date = new Date(1452413972759l);
String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
System.out.println("Today is " + sdf.format(date));
```